# How to set the border color of a Area chart in MVVM?

Tags: css, html, mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui

How to set the border color of a Area chart in MVVM?

```
<div data-role="chart"
 data-legend="{ position: 'bottom' }"
 data-series-defaults="{ type: 'area' }"
 data-series-colors="['#A2A2A2']"

 data-series="[
                 { field: 'id', name: 'id' , labels: {visible: true},line: {style:'smooth'}}
             ]"

 data-bind="source: sourceId,
            events: { seriesHover: onSeriesHoverIndex }"
 style="height: 250px;" >
```

Something like this attached image
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which part exactly of the chart do you refer to as "the border"? Can you post an image and mark the border you speak of?

Comment: Yes, i just done

Comment: Do you mean the chart line, the area under the line, the background or is it something else? Color it in red in the image you posted so that it will be clear.